# android studio cannot resolve symbol R.raw

Tags: android

I'm working on a database so I created an android raw resource directory but when I try to access the files in it android tells me that it can't resolve for raw. Also any sub directory that I add won't show up in my project manager but does appear in the file explorer.

This is how I create the folder.

right click on **res** -> **New** -> **Android Resource Directory** -> **Resource Type** *raw* -> **ok**

This is how I get access to the files.

```
private Context context;
private Resources res = context.getResources();
InputStream stream = res.openRawResource(R.raw.phase1).
```

But android tells me that it can't resolve raw symbol.

Comment: Where did you add the raw folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add raw resource directory in Resource .. If you still can't resolve raw symbol rebuild project.

[image: Like this]

Comment: I do have the folder in resources and rebuilding doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: so u can invalidate caches /restart.. or delete caches folder from Android Studio Folder where u installed